Large vertex-boundary implies long path
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph on more than $k$ vertices and for each $k$-set $S\subset V$ we have $|\partial S|\geq l.$ Show that $G$ has a path of length $l-1$.
The definition of boundary is
$$\partial S=\{v\not\in S:\exists u\in S,uv\in E\}.$$
My attempt:
When $k=1$, this is a well-known result. When $k=2$, take $S$ to be the two end vertices of the longest path will fix this problem.
When $k\geq 3$, I have no idea, as there is no structure of a path that will behave well when considering no less than $3$ vertices.

What have you tried?

This probably won't help much, but for a graph $G$ with longest path of length $c$, if you take a maximal independent set $I$ and consider the subgraph induced on the vertices $V(G) - I$, then the longest path in that graph is bounded by $c-1$.
